# How to predict values with sklearn KNN

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I can't make predictions with sklearn KNN model.

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn.datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

data = sklearn.datasets.load_digits()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data['data'], data['target'])
model = KNeighborsClassifier().fit(X_train, y_train)
print(model.predict(X_test[0]))
```

it returns an error

```
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

and when i reshape it with

```
print(model.predict(X_test[0].reshape(-1, 1))
```

it stills return an error

```
ValueError: query data dimension must match training data dimension
```

Comment: Can you print the dimensions of `X_test[0].reshape(-1, 1)` and check if they match with that of the training data `X_train`? The number of columns must be equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to predict for the first test row, so you should be reshaping as `(1, -1)` instead ("it contains a single sample" from the error message).